# Why won't SO let me answer my own question?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, self-answer

I had a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429821/jenkins-make-pass-fail-dependent-on-results-from-script-command) that I figured out the answer to, but when I clicked on the "Answer Your Question" button, the page doesn't seem to respond at all. I've had this problem before with other questions too. Why won't it let me do this?

Edit: For the record, I just checked on this question and it's doing the same thing here.

Comment: Stupid question, but you *do* have JavaScript enabled, yes? Clicking the option to Answer Your Question should open up an answer field at the bottom of the page, but won't work without JScript. Also, by 'Doesn't Seem to respond' do you mean nothing happens? Does the checkbox get ticked? Do you get any feedback?

Comment: @JonW I had the same thought initially so I checked, but it looks like JS is enabled for all everything on my browser. When I click the button, it just seems like there's no feedback at all, no page refresh or anything, nothing (at least visibly) changes on the page.

Comment: @thnkwthprtls There *shouldn't* be a page refresh, just a new textbox shown.

Comment: Can you post an answer at all?

Comment: @Servy OK I wasn't sure, either way nothing happens, no new textbox.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No

Comment: @thnkwthprtls He means to another question, one that's not yours.

Comment: Oh sorry, in that case yes, I can post answers to other questions, just not my own

Comment: Are you using Chrome?  Try a different browser.

Comment: Disable all your user scripts, browser add-ons etc... 99% one of them is messing with the JavaScript required to answer your own question.

Comment: On other peoples questions the answer box is there by default, its only on your own questions that you have to click a button

Comment: @RobertHarvey switching to Firefox did it, thanks :)

Comment: Your welcome.  Chrome used to be my favorite browser; now it's my least favorite browser.  Someone over there at Google needs to open up a can of whupass.

Comment: @RichardTingle or if you already have an answer on that post; it then requires a button click to add another.

Comment: Maybe it's the [new user](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to figure out how to do this (obviously, since I'm doing it here), it ended up being an issue with my browser, it was giving me issues in Chrome but then worked in Firefox.